# Fair downvoting

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, down-votes

Throughout my experience in the Stack Overflow forum I have noticed something that really bothers me: the downvoting system. It's not that I feel that downvotes shouldn't exist; I simply believe that there should be a way for the person who gets downvoted to know the reason.

I have gotten downvoted numerous times in questions that I think are perfectly normal. I consider that it is a coward act to downvote without explaining what the downvoted did wrong. And since the downvotes are anonymous, everyone can just do it for no reason.

**My proposal for the feature that should be implemented is the following:**

When a person clicks the downvote button there should be a textbox that pops up in which the downvoter has to clarify the reason for the downvote. Downvotes could still be anonymous but this way the downvoted would get an information as to why their post got downvoted.

If the downvoted feels like the explanation the downvoter gave isn't enough then they could send it to a moderator for them to check it out.

What do you think? This is the way I made up to deal with it, but maybe there is a better way. Please comment and answer.

*PS: Sorry for writing downvote so many times.*

Comment: *This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful* How much more reason or explanation is needed for my down vote?

Comment: Also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51522/request-confirmation-pop-up-before-downvoting

Comment: Also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44977/down-voting-perfectly-good-questions-without-leaving-a-comment

Comment: _"...  the Stack Overflow forum ..."_ Fundamental misconception! Stack Overflow or any other SE sites aren't _forums_. They are meant as FAQ like Q&A repositories, helpful in long term research.

Comment: If a reason was required to be shared "NA" would be the reason I would use.  If I feel like getting revenge votes I leave a comment often my vote speaks for itself (I.e the question isn't even on topic)

Comment: Only if upvotes also had to be justified as well.  Not such a reasonable request now, is it?

Answer (score 15):

Most of this is a duplicate, but one part of your question isn't so I'll address that:

> If the downvoted feels like the explanation the downvoter gave isn't enough then they could send it to a moderator for them to check it out.

As a moderator, I am *not interested* in adjudicating disputes over votes.  *Not our job,* unless there is a pattern of questionable behavior.  Moderators are not arbiters of correctness; we don't even police wrong answers,<sup>1</sup> so we're sure not going to police votes.

Even if that weren't true, you're asking for moderators to be called into a discussion over nearly every downvote on the site.  That would be a huge time-drain for volunteers whose primary job is to keep the site running smoothly.

If you think something bad, even abusive, is going on, then flag.  But asking for a vote-by-vote review is not a reasonable request.  And while you probably don't think you're asking for a vote-by-vote review, that's what it'll turn into (nearly), because it costs the user almost nothing to ask and he might get his 2 points back.

<sup>1</sup> *Non*-answers, yes, via flags, but not *wrong* ones.  That's what downvotes are for.  One of the specific flag-rejection reaasons is: *flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer*.

Comment: Might be worth pointing out too that *flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer* is actually a specific reason to reject a flag. So is *flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention*.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling good point; added the first.

Answer (score 4):

When a user under 2000 rep downvotes a post, they get a red popup encouraging them to comment why they casted that downvote.

It is not your job to judge whether the downvotes was right or not but to try to fix your post so it is of better quality and fits the Help Center requirements. The moderators' job is to moderate the site by closing, reopening, reviewing flags, etc. but not to simply handle dispute over votes. We cannot judge your judgement nor can you judge ours. Anyways compared to an upvote, downvotes aren't really that harmful and the 1 rep penalty on an downvote on an answer will make sure that users think twice about voting.